# insert, update and remove vs insertOne, updateOne and deleteOne (or -Many)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a bit confused wether to use:
- insert() vs insertOne() or insertMany()
- update() vs updateOne() or updateMany()
- remove() vs deleteOne() or deleteMany()

Following the [MongoDB Crud Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/), only the xxOne() and xxMany() are mentioned. However, many online resources use the simple terms (and then use the methods options arguments for multiple or single documents).

I've read at one place that the simple terms are deprecated and therefore the xxOne() and xxMany() are recommended. Is this true or could you still use the simple terms?

Personally, the xxOne() and xxMany() methods make it more obvious what the method does, but I feel like that the simple terms are straightforward and better.

**Edit:**

It looks like MongoDB shell still supports the simple terms, but major drivers (such as Mongoose for NodeJS) has deprecated the simple terms in favor for the xxOne() and xxMany() methods.
[Mongoose Source](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)

Answer (score 1):

`Insert` is used to insert documents in our collection.

```
db.test.insert({ "key": "value1","key2":"Val2","key3":"val3" })
```

or we can use

```
db.test.insert({ "key": "value1","key2":"Val2","key3":"val3" })
```

`InsertOne` is used to insert only one record

```
db.test.insertOne({"key":"value"});
```

Use `insertMany` whenever you want to insert multiple records

```
d.test.insert([{"key":"value"}, {"key":"value"}]);
```

`Insert` is highlighted as `deprecated` in every official language driver since version 3.0. The shell methods actually lagged behind the other drivers in implementing the methods. The same thing applies for All the **CRUD** methods.

Update the entire Object

```
db.test.update({name:'Thyame'}, {age:22, name:'Thyame'});
```

the new feature in `MongoDB 3.2`

```
db.test.updateOne({name: 'Thyame'},{age: 22, name: 'Thyame'}) //Will replace only first matching document.

db.test.updateMany({name: 'Thyame'},{age: 22, name: 'Thyame'}) //Will replace all matching documents.
//new in MongoDb 3.2

 db.test.updateOne({name: 'Thyame'},{$set:{age: 22}) //Will update only first matching document.

db.test.updateMany({name: 'Tom'},{$set:{age: 22}}) //Will update all matching documents.
```

Fields that you use to identify the object will be saved in the updated documents. And the field that are not defined in the update section will be removed from the documents.

Whereas in `delete` in  all version

```
db.test.remove({name:'Thyame'}); // this will work
```

and what's new in MongoDB's version 3.2 is

```
db.test.removeMany({name:'Thyame'});
```

And if you execute this command without any argument it will remove all the documents from your collection.

And yes, Mongoose for NodeJs has deprecated the method like  they replace `update()` with `updateOne` or `replaceOne()` and many more methods

Comment: Thanks for your effort but you talked around the question. I know what each one of the method does - but which one to use. After some additional research, I've figured out that you shouldn't use the simple terms anymore because they are deprecated. Not gonna mark this as the answer but still an upvote